# JScrollBars setValue не опускается в самый низ

Tags: java, swing

Использую `JScrollPane`. В нем находится `JTextArea`. Я хочу сделать `JTextArea.setText()` и опустить вертикальный `ScrollBar` в самый низ.

Код:

```
final JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane panelSCROLL = new JScrollPane(text);
text.setText(text.getText().concat(new String(БАЙТЫ ИЗ ФАЙЛА)));
panelSCROLL.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(panelSCROLL.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
```

Но `ScrollBar` опускается не в самый низ, а на прежнюю позицию, то есть максимум, который был еще до `setText`;

А вот и пример:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class JavaApplication19 {
    static JScrollPane scrollPane = null;
    static JTextArea text = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
        testFrame.setTitle("TEST");

        text = new JTextArea();
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(text);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout group = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(testFrame);
        //testFrame.setLayout(group);

        group.setHorizontalGroup(group.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(scrollPane,0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        group.setVerticalGroup(group.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(scrollPane,0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        text.setText("TEST");
        int a = 0;
        int max = 40;
        while(a!=max){
            text.append("\nTEST");
            a = a + 1;
        }

        testFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        testFrame.setVisible(true);

        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1300);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
                text.append("\nTEST");
                text.append("\nTEST");
                scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

А если сделать вот так

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1300);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        text.append("\nTEST");
        text.append("\nTEST");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar()
                  .setValue(scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
    }
}.start();
```

То все отлично работает, но ожидание в 200 миллисекунд ради `ScrollBar` это плохо.

Не предлагать `text.setCaretPosition(text.getDocument().getLength());` у меня этот баг работает, даже если я использую объекты, а не просто `JTextArea`.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, минимальный компилируемый код. Это означает, что код должен компилироваться и в нём не должно быть лишних элементов.

Comment: Я этот камент встречал уже, слово в слово пишите! И чем вам не нравится мой минимально компилируемый код?

Comment: [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Я заглянул в свой хрустальный шар, и прозреваю, что вы читаете файл в отдельном потоке (или даже в main)

Comment: Про файл я так случайно сказал, а так это не только в JTextArea, а вообще если разместить обьекты на JScrollPane то ScrollBar опустится на прежнюю позицию

Comment: в общем, пишите программу, которая воспроизводит проблему, так, чтобы ее можно было скомпилировать и запустить, просто вставив в пустой файл.

Comment: Ха, шар-то работает. Заверните `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());` в `SwingUtilities.invokeLater( ... )`, и старайтесь не обращаться к компонентам Swing не из EDT. В прогрессивных тулкитах за такое прилетают исключения, свинг старенький и толерантный.

Comment: Хм, а я все думал что это за SwingUtilities, все работает спасибо, пойду на проекте тестить, ответьте на вопрос отмечу как верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина происходящего - [race condition](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) между процессом, добавляющим данные в `JTextArea` (ваш `new Thread(){}`) и `EventDispatchThread` - рабочим процессом Swing/AWT.

Чтобы решить проблему, нужно выполнять все операции с компонентами Swing в EDT, для чего служат методы [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable doRun)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-) и `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable doRun)`. Оба метода добавляют переданный код в конец очереди событий EDT. Поскольку нет необходимости ждать завершения операции, подойдет последний:

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1300);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {
            text.append("\nTEST");
            text.append("\nTEST");
            scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
        });
    }
}.start();
```

---

Race condition возникает, т.к. Swing выполняет все операции обновления UI в EDT. Когда вы меняете текст в `JTextArea`, компонент решает, что нужно  пересчитать размеры и перерисоваться, для чего вызывает `JComponent.revalidate()`. Внутри `revalidate()` проверяется, что текущий процесс - Event Dispatch Thread. Поскольку это не так, перерисовка ставится в очередь событий в EDT и управление возвращается в ваш код. Ваш код далее запрашивает максимальное положение для полосы прокрутки, и дальнейшее зависит от того, успел ли пересчет размера выполниться в EDT, и увидит ли ваш процесс новый размер.

При обработке событий Swing (нажатия кнопок и т.п.) этой проблемы нет, т.к. обработчики выполняются в EDT.

Чтобы избежать тормозов интерфейса, код, передаваемый в `invokeLater` должен выполняться быстро, т.е.:

```
// плохо
SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {
    text.append( getStringFromSlowNetwork() );
});

// лучше так:
final String string = getStringFromSlowNetwork();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {
    text.append( string );
});
```

Для длительных операций можно воспользоваться классом [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), который предоставляет шаблон фонового задания с возможностью публикации промежуточных результатов.

- Java Turtorials: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)